# How to make instagram iframe repsonsive without JS?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, instagram, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive grid with instagram posts and padding-bottom hack doesn't work in my case. I did a simple jQuery script, i found that height = width + 306px.

How i did it:

```
let $instagramPosts = $('.instagram-post'),
    width = $instagramPosts.eq(0).width(),
    differenceWH = 306;

$instagramPosts.height(width + differenceWH);
```

Is it possible to make it without JS just with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into css `calc()` as I don't know your initial height I am gonna assume it is x. So for the calculation, you can do this

```
.instagram-post {
    height:calc(x + 306px);
}
```